# How to get the exception ID and Title from Play!Framework?

Tags: exception, logging, playframework-2.1

I'm using Play!Framework with Java and I'd like to display in the console the exception ID and the title of the exception, and only that.

For testing, I created a Global object like this :

```
public class Global extends GlobalSettings {
    @Override
    public Result onError(RequestHeader request, Throwable throwable) {
        Logger.info(Json.toJson(throwable).toString());
        return super.onError(request, throwable);
    }
}
```

This outputs a JSON formatted value of Throwable, wich contains this :

```
{
    "cause": { ... },
    "stackTrace": [ ... ],
    "title": "Execution exception",
    "description": "[NullPointerException: null]",
    "id": "6epj67c35",
    "message": "Execution exception[[NullPointerException: null]]",
    "localizedMessage": "Execution exception[[NullPointerException: null]]",
    "suppressed": []
}
```

Which proves that id and title are accessible, but if I try:

```
throwable.getId(); // does not exists
throwable.getTitle(); // Does not neither
```

So then, how can I access id and title ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For that one, I looked at the [Play20 code at Github](https://github.com/playframework/Play20/), more precisely at those two classes :

- [UsefulException.java](https://github.com/playframework/Play20/blob/master/framework/src/play-exceptions/src/main/java/play/api/UsefulException.java)
- [PlayException.java](https://github.com/playframework/Play20/blob/master/framework/src/play-exceptions/src/main/java/play/api/PlayException.java)

And in fact, Play throws a PlayException that extends UsefullException, containing the id, title and description. So here's how I did it :

```
public class Global extends GlobalSettings {
    @Override
    public Result onError(RequestHeader request, Throwable throwable) {
        if (throwable instanceof PlayException) {
            Logger.info(((PlayException) throwable).id);
        }
        return super.onError(request, throwable);
    }
}
```

That's it ! :)